# Apache POI: how to get page number when iterating over docx.getBodyElements()

Tags: java, apache-poi

When iterating over a document the following way:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));

for (IBodyElement bodyElement : docx.getBodyElements()) {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to know what page (page range) current IBodyElement belongs to?

Comment: Short answer - no. Word doesn't generally store that information in the file format, it's calculated on-the-fly when the file is opened based on available fonts etc

Comment: @Gagravarr Does it mean page numbers are not consistent across devices for the same document?

Comment: Nope! If you need that, swap to PDF